# How to mimic jQuery insertBefore appendTo etc on a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am having real issues getting my head around this one, so I hope I can explain it adequately!

I have an array of elements that I need to insert into array at different specific positions.

so I have this (there could also be 'prependTo'):-

```
$merged_movers = Array(
[class:ics-header] => insertBefore(class:ics-page-holder)
[class:ics-secondary] => insertAfter(class:ics-primary)
[class:ics-footer] => appendTo(class:ics-page)
[class:ics-full-side-2] => insertBefore(class:ics-page)
)
```

That I need to insert into this:-

```
$default_structure = Array
 (
  [class:ics-page-holder] => Array
    (
        [class:ics-full-side-1] => class:ics-full-side-1
        [class:ics-page] => Array
            (
                [class:ics-topblock] => class:ics-topblock
                [class:ics-main] => Array
                    (
                        [class:ics-main-top] => class:ics-main-top
                        [class:ics-primary] => Array
                            (
                                [class:ics-primary-top] => class:ics-primary-top
                                [class:ics-article] => class:ics-article
                                [class:ics-article2] => class:ics-article2
                                [class:ics-primary-bottom] => class:ics-primary-bottom
                            )

                        [class:ics-tertiary] => class:ics-tertiary
                        [class:ics-main-bottom] => class:ics-main-bottom
                    )

                [class:ics-bottomblock] => class:ics-bottomblock
            )

    )
)
```

and I need to end up with this:-

```
[class:ics-header] => class:ics-header
    [class:ics-page-holder] => Array
    (
        [class:ics-full-side-1] => class:ics-full-side-1
        [class:ics-full-side-2] => class:ics-full-side-2
        [class:ics-page] => Array
            (
                [class:ics-topblock] => class:ics-topblock
                [class:ics-main] => Array
                    (
                        [class:ics-main-top] => class:ics-main-top
                        [class:ics-primary] => Array
                            (
                                [class:ics-primary-top] => class:ics-primary-top
                                [class:ics-article] => class:ics-article
                                [class:ics-article2] => class:ics-article2
                                [class:ics-primary-bottom] => class:ics-primary-bottom
                            )

                        [class:ics-secondary] => class:ics-secondary
                        [class:ics-tertiary] => class:ics-tertiary
                        [class:ics-main-bottom] => class:ics-main-bottom
                    )

                [class:ics-bottomblock] => class:ics-bottomblock
            )

         [class:ics-footer] => class:ics-footer

    )
```

I have tried every array_merge, array_merge recursive etc I can find but noting gives me that order so what I am trying to do is iterate through the second array and if its key matches one of the bits in brackets in the value from first array insert the element from the first array according to that keys insertBefore/prependTo etc value.

but I just cannot work out how to get array elements added into the second array at certain positions rather than at the end of each (recursive) block...

Really hope someone might be able to give me some pointers...

UPDATE this is what I am trying... insertBefore and appendTo seem to work ok but insertAfter is appending and I cannot work out how to stop it (not sure about prepedTo

```
$new_default_structure = $default_structure;
foreach($merged_movers as $el => $pos_settings)
    {
    $pos_setting = explode('(',rtrim($pos_settings, ')'));
    $position = $pos_setting[0];
    $position_relation = $pos_setting[1];
    parse_icl_structure_reset_els(&$new_default_structure, $el, $el_content[$el], $position, $position_relation);
    }
```

which calls this:-

```
function parse_icl_structure_reset_els(&$default_structure, $el, $el_content, $position, $position_relation, &$insertbefore='', &$insertafter='') {
if($insertbefore != '')
    {
    foreach($insertbefore as $key2 => $value2)
        $default_structure[$key2] = $value2;
        $insertbefore = '';
    }
foreach($default_structure as $key => &$value)
    {
    if($key == $position_relation)
        {
        if($position == 'insertBefore')//this might be working
            {
            $holdingkey = $value;
            unset($default_structure[$key]);
            $default_structure[$el.'insertBefore'] = $el_content;
            $default_structure[$key] = $value;
            if(is_array($value))
                parse_icl_structure_reset_els(&$value, $el, $el_content, $position, $position_relation, &$insertbefore, &$insertafter);
            }
        if($position == 'insertAfter')//this seems to do what I want appendTo to do
            {
            if(is_array($value))
                parse_icl_structure_reset_els(&$value, $el, $el_content, $position, $position_relation, &$insertbefore, &$insertafter);
            else
                $value[$key] = $value;
            $value[$el.'insertAfter'] = $el_content;
            }
        if($position == 'appendTo')
            {
            if(is_array($value))
                parse_icl_structure_reset_els(&$value, $el, $el_content, $position, $position_relation, &$insertbefore, &$insertafter);
            else
                $value[$key] = $value;
            $value[$el.'appendTo'] = $el_content;
            }
        }
    elseif(is_array($value))
        {
         parse_icl_structure_reset_els(&$value, $el, $el_content, $position, $position_relation, &$insertbefore, &$insertafter);    
        }
    }
}
```

and that gives me this

```
[class:ics-headerinsertBefore] => class:ics-header
[class:ics-page-holder] => Array
    (
        [class:ics-full-side-1] => class:ics-full-side-1
        [class:ics-full-side-2insertBefore] => class:ics-full-side-2
        [class:ics-page] => Array
            (
                [class:ics-topblock] => class:ics-topblock
                [class:ics-main] => Array
                    (
                        [class:ics-main-top] => class:ics-main-top
                        [class:ics-primary] => Array
                            (
                                [class:ics-primary-top] => class:ics-primary-top
                                [class:ics-article] => class:ics-article
                                [class:ics-article2] => class:ics-article2
                                [class:ics-primary-bottom] => class:ics-primary-bottom
                                [class:ics-secondaryinsertAfter] => class:ics-secondary
                            )

                        [class:ics-tertiary] => class:ics-tertiary
                        [class:ics-main-bottom] => class:ics-main-bottom
                    )

                [class:ics-bottomblock] => class:ics-bottomblock
                [class:ics-footerappendTo] => class:ics-footer
            )

    )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you're iterating and recursing, make sure you use _references_. That way, when you make changes to the array, it modifies the original data, not a copy.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, you can't expect people to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: yep will do, its all such a chaotic mess right now but will edit post shortly

Answer (score 0):

Ok think I cracked it!

First thing to do was change the structure of the $merged_movers array so that the keys were the elements that were already in the default structure array...

```
foreach($merged_movers as $move_el => $pos_settings)
    {
    $pos_setting = explode('(',rtrim($pos_settings, ')'));
    $position = $pos_setting[0];
    $target = $pos_setting[1];
    $new_merged_movers[$target][$move_el] = $position;  
    }
$merged_movers = $new_merged_movers;
```

So now that array looks like this

```
[class:ics-page-holder] => Array
    (
        [class:ics-header] => insertBefore
    )

[class:ics-primary] => Array
    (
        [class:ics-secondary] => insertAfter
    )

[class:ics-page] => Array
    (
        [class:ics-footer] => appendTo
        [class:ics-full-side-2] => insertBefore
    )
```

then I call $structureOut = parse_icl_structure_reset_els($default_structure, $merged_movers, $prependTo='', $appendTo='');

which is this function

```
function parse_icl_structure_reset_els($default_structure, $merged_movers, $prependTo='', $appendTo='') {
if(is_array($prependTo))
    {
    foreach($prependTo as $el => $val)
        {
        $newStructure[$el] = $el;   
        }
    $prependTo = '';    
    }
foreach($default_structure as $key => $value)
    {
    if(array_key_exists($key,$merged_movers))
        {
        foreach($merged_movers[$key] as $el => $pos)
            {
            if($pos == 'insertBefore')
                {
                $newStructure[$el] = $el;
                }
            elseif($pos == 'prependTo' || $pos == 'appendTo')
                {
                if($pos == 'prependTo')
                    {
                    $prependTo[$el] = $key;
                    }
                if($pos == 'appendTo')
                    {
                    $appendTo[$el] = $key;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    if(is_array($value))
        {
        $this_content_array = parse_icl_structure_reset_els($value, $merged_movers, $prependTo, $appendTo);
        if(is_array($prependTo))
            {
            foreach($prependTo as $el => $val)
                {
                if($val == $key)
                    {
                    $out_content_array[$el] = $el;
                    $out_modified = true;
                    unset($prependTo[$el]);
                    }   
                }
            if($out_modified == true)
                {
                foreach($this_content_array as $pkey => $pvalue)
                    {
                    $out_content_array[$pkey] = $pvalue;
                    }
                $this_content_array = $out_content_array;
                $out_modified = false;
                }
            }
        if(is_array($appendTo))
            {
            foreach($appendTo as $el => $val)
                {
                if($val == $key)
                    {
                    $this_content_array[$el] = $el; 
                    unset($appendTo[$el]);
                    }
                }   
            }
        $newStructure[$key] = $this_content_array;
        }
    else
        {
        $newStructure[$key] = $value;   
        }
    if(array_key_exists($key,$merged_movers))
        {
        foreach($merged_movers[$key] as $el => $pos)
            {
            if($pos == 'insertAfter')
                {
                $newStructure[$el] = $el;   
                }
            }
        }
    }
return $newStructure;
}
```

Amazing what a help a good nights sleep can be ;)

Only issue left is that the inserted elements content may itself be an array...hmm